# Find documents by author first or last name and title

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

If I have this schema for art projects.

```
var projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    authors: [String],
    title: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Project", projectSchema);
```

Where the `authors` is an array of Strings and `title` is a single String.

Example of one document:

```
{
    authors: ["Will Jackson", "Mary Price"],
    title: "Blue sky and green land"
}
```

How can I find all projects that have author with first or last name *"Jakson"* and have word *"Sky"* in their title (**Both queries must not be case sensitive!**)

I was hoping for something along the lines of:

```
Projects.find( {authors : {$in : "Jackson"}}, {title : "Sky"});
```

I assume that some `$regex` query is missing here. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do multiple text search using "$text query and $or" in mongodb / mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31160505/how-to-do-multiple-text-search-using-text-query-and-or-in-mongodb-mongoose)

Answer (score 0):

i think solution should be:-

```
Projects.find(
  // Find documents matching any of these values
  {$and:[
    {"authors" : {"$in":[/jackson/]}},
    {"title" : {"$in":"/Sky/"}}
  ]}
)
```

Comment: I get **MongoError: $in needs an array**

Comment: okk double quotes was interpreted as strings. check now. or check this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35321004/mongodb-query-in-with-regex-array-of-element